# CSS - SVG on full page [Anime JS]

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, web-frontend

currently I am trying to add an animation to my heading. In this example I just use ABC.

I got it like:`|   A   B    C   |` I would like to achieve following: `|      ABC      |`

And move a letter for example 100px to the right and vertically to the bottom of the page.

I tried to create an element over the whole page where I can move each SVG Letter by X and Y how I want, without being cut off. But I am not the best in css...

This is currently my code. https://jsfiddle.net/zw67g8dc/

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: like that? - https://ibb.co/Pxcpk4t

Comment: yes like that. vertically and horicontally centered, looking like a "normal" heading without spaces between the letter

Comment: Okay, but what do you mean? - *"And move a letter for example 100px to the right and vertically to the bottom of the page."* **and** *"I tried to create an element over the whole page where I can move each SVG Letter by X and Y how I want, without being cut off."*

Comment: as you can see on the jsfiddle, I added an animation with animeJS but the letter "B" is cut off if I move it to the bottom.